# Update UI multiple times during Activity method

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-activity

In my main activity I have a method linked to a button, when the button is pressed it should be disabled, then a HTTP request is made and after the method finishes the button should be enabled again.

```
public void onClick(View view) {        
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    try {
        // make HTTP request
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // error
    } finally {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

So normally the button should change color after I clicked it, then I wait for the request to happen which will timeout, hence I wait for 3 seconds, and then the button's color should change back.

Unfortunately the color/button is not updated once, until the method finishes. What is the reason for that? How is it done properly?

Comment: It seems like you're saying "Unfortunately the color is not updated until the method finishes." Isn't that what you want to happen? Can you clarify what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make the HTTP call (place it in the method: [doInBackground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) ) and put the code to re-enable the button again on the method [onPostExecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

Comment: Wonderful yes, that should do

Comment: This doesn't work well with Activity restart during orientation change. Backgrond work in Android is unfortunately hard to do properly.